# SNMP OID for network traffic

Tags: snmp, nagios, net-snmp, oid, mib

i'm working on a script that will monitor traffic on specific hosts from nagios. I have studied some scripts already made and have gathered almost all the info i need to do it but i have encountered a problem in identifying the OID's necessary for the traffic. I wanted to use `IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.1` and `IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1` to get the incoming and outgoing traffic but when i tested with the following line:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public myComputer OID
```

i got the same result for both the OID's and that doesn't seem right. I'm wandering if there are other variables i could try instead of those i'm using now.

It would be useful even if you can point me to where i could find some info on the `IF-MIB`, because i can get all the values with `snmpwalk` but i don't know how to interpret them

Comment: why not http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToContactNagios

Comment: I'm kinda forced to use snmp, because i have the daemon on the station i have to monitor, and i can't install anything more. But i found something that explains the `IF-MiB` : http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/mfd/if-mib/index.html

Comment: Another good source of information is Pro Python System Administration by Rytis Sileika from Apress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer, after some searching. The values are equal because i was not asking the right interface(i was asking the loopback). There is this command `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public hostname 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1` that lists a lot of OID's and from there you can see 'IF-MIB::ifName' which stand for the interfaces. And if you execute `IF-MIB::ifInOctets.x` where x corresponds to the interface you are interested in you can find a number in bytes. I am not sure what it means, or how it's generated but i tested executing twice the command:

```
date ; snmpwalk -v 1 -c public myComputer ifOutOctets.x
```

at an interval of aprox 1 min, and then i subtracted the two values and devided them by the number of seconds that passed between the executions. I compared the value with the one obtained from iptraf and they kinda match, so i think you can used this way to find the traffic a station with snmp.